# SyntaxError positional argument follows keyword argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error, keyword-argument, positional-argument

I am wondering if the below statement is correct.

***SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument***

I know what is positional argument and keyword argument but getting confused with the above statement. for example when we say

***A follows B It means***

*//It means that “A” comes after “B”*

So in the same way when we are calling any function then we should pass the **positional** argument first and then the **keyword** argument. And in that case, correct statement should be

```
***SyntaxError: keyword argument follows positional argument***
```

example:

```
    def test(a,b,c):
        print(f"Sum of all no is : {a+b+c}")
    test(a=10,20,c=30)
    test(a=10,20,c=30)
//output                   ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

example2:

```
Passing positional argument first.
    def test(a,b,c):
        print(f"Sum of all no is : {a+b+c}")
    test(20,c=10,b=30)
    //output
    Sum of all no is : 60
```

Comment: I think the error is pointing out what is wrong, not what the correct syntax should be.

Comment: The error message is correct. Consider if `test()` had two parameters and you called `test(a=20, 10)`.

Comment: My Bad, Got It Thanks! @quamrana (It is pointing out what is wrong in the current code and not what should be syntax : ) ).

Answer (score 0):

That's a feature of Python syntax. It interprets positional arguments in the order in which they appear first and then followed by the keyword arguments as next. For example this code:

```
def test(a,b,c):
    print(f"Sum of all no is : {a+b+c}")
test(10,20,a=30)
```

Returns "TypeError: test() got multiple values for argument 'a' ". Because Python positionally interprets 10 and 20 as the first two variables, so 'a' and 'b' are already used